# How to load Postgres from schema and restore the data from existing from table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm working on a rails application where we made changes to the schema directly without writing migration files. Now I want load the schema in the development machine to Staging server.  But if I did `rake db:schema:load`, It will erase the data in the database.

Is there anyway to solve this problem? I want to restore the data in the table after running `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: have you try with `rake db:rollback` ?

Comment: You can always dump and reload the data from PostgreSQL without using Rails. So dump your data from developmenet database first, then load it into your staging one after db:schema:load. As long as the shema is the same, there is not problem at all. I use what Heroku suggests to move data from remote PostgreSQL to local one during development (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).